# Use Inkscape project in an animation app

Tags: inkscape, vector, software-recommendation, animation

I have a few .svg files from Inkscape that I would like to animate. However, I am not aware of a simple-to-use software that would let me paste it in its app and move my vectors in it to create the animation. I've tried on OpenToonz and on Krita so far and nothing is pasted when copying my vectors from Inkscape. I've just started graphic illustration so I would like a program easy to use to animate my work.

I was wondering if anyone had recommendations for this, i.e. transporting an Inkscape project into an animation app and continue the work there.

Comment: There are many.. but if "free" is a factor, that may be another matter.

Comment: Free is a factor hahahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your file as .sif file and then animate it with synfig studio.